# How to create responsive website using javascript and media queries?

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

I want to make my website responsive with the following conditions:

1. The navigation bar must be a hamburger drop-down menu vertically when the screen is scaled down and coding must be java-script
2. I want to use media queries to achieve mobile first strategy.

I am a bit confused here because all the tutorial I watched on you tube is about Bootstrap and I do not like that.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I suggested use Bootstrap in your website because Bootstrap in include all elements and components with responsive. This all useful for build a new website.

Comment: @KoratPrakash That's the case! I do not want to use bootstrap frame-work because I want to learn how to hard code it!

Comment: Okay, You can use HTML5, css3 and latest jquery to build a website.

Comment: can I send my code over and you edit it?

Comment: @KoratPrakash  can I send the code ?

Comment: Please, put your code here or in code pen and people may be willing to help you correct or adapt it.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest looking at free online resources to learn media queries. Two quality trusted sources that I reference frequently are the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), and [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp).

Here is an example of a media query as shown from the second link above:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}
```

The idea is to layout your page for smaller viewports first, and then change your layout, usually using css, as the screen size gets larger. Hence the term "mobile first". This is normally the best way to approach layout not only because mobile web traffic has overtaken larger view port web browsing, but also because mobile versions of sites tend to be more simple and streamlined. Its easier to add complexity as viewport size increases versus the opposite.

As far as the hamburger menu, here is a [W3 School's tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp) to help you learn and give you some code to play with. Be sure to make your browser window smaller and larger to see the effect:

```js
/* Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to topnav when the user clicks on the icon */
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

```css
/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */
.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
.topnav .icon {
    display: none;
}

/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Load an icon library to show a hamburger menu (bars) on small screens -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

A basic overview of whats happening is that in combination with styles changing according to the media queries being applied (at different viewport widths), the style also changes when the hamburger menu is clicked because of the [JavaScript .onclick method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) listening for a click event on the element. When the element is clicked the JavaScript [manipulates the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents) and changes that element by changing it's [className property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className). With different classes being applied that changes the styling. So in short when someone clicks the hamburger icon the layout of the page changes.

So in order to create good mobile responsive sites, without using frameworks like Bootstrap and assuming you have good understanding of HTML, you should at the very least learn:

- Media queries
- Using css to layout the page
- Manipulating the DOM with Javascript

Comment: Thanks alot. That will clear some confusion.

Comment: could i send my website over and you try it???